# How can I install Ubuntu on my new desktop?

Tags: system-installation

I am currently using a laptop and would like to keep my laptop running Windows 7. I want Ubuntu on my new desktop I just built because (at the moment) I don't have ~150 dollars to dish out for an OS. I don't have a disk drive, so I will be using USB. I know it involves burning a .ISO file to a USB , but I'm not sure how. Thanks!

Comment: Here you should found everything you need:  How to make bootable USB disk: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows , How to install: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick Another question about same thing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the previous answer's suggestion, Unetbootin doesn't always provide a Bootable medium. I'd recommend using Rufus to burn your ISO to a USB drive. I can't post links right now, but searching `Rufus usb` will yield the program as the first result. For more reference, check out the links suggested in the comments of your question.